# Implementing Screenplay Pattern/Actor Model in a UI test automation framework in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I'm curious about the implementation of the screenplay pattern / actor model within a test automation framework in .NET.

Benefits I foresee for using this pattern in test automation are:

- Separate business domain from test logic (BDD driven)
- Business readable (actor performs and observes)
- Tasks (group of actions) are not necessarily required in reporting (Given/Then)
- Tests are more resilient in that setup/teardown tasks are handled better
- Underlying automation should be able to execute anywhere (Web/UI/API) - Agnostic

Research:

This has been achieved with the Java BDD automation framework, Serenity BDD (formerly known as [Thucydides](http://www.thucydides.info/#/))

Possible .NET implementations could include using the following technologies:

- NUnit/MSTest/XUnit
- SpecFlow/Gherkin
- Akka.Net

My question is: Has anybody implemented this within the .NET framework for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check out the following library: [CSF.Screenplay](https://github.com/csf-dev/CSF.Screenplay)

It's a library inspired by [Serenity](https://github.com/serenity-bdd), a testing framework which includes a Java implementation of the Screenplay pattern.

The preferred integration for using this library in .NET is SpecFlow. But here's an example using NUnit instead, as it is more concise and more widely recognized.

```
[TestFixture]
[Description("Users should be able to buy groceries via the web application")]
public class UsersCanBuyGroceries
{
    [Test,Screenplay]
    [Description("Joe should see a thankyou message when he uses the web application to buy eggs.")]
    public void JoeShouldSeeAThankyouMessageWhenHeBuysEggs(ICast cast, BrowseTheWeb browseTheWeb)
    {
        var joe = cast.Get("Joe")
        joe.IsAbleTo(browseTheWeb);
        Given(joe).WasAbleTo(SearchTheShop.ForGroceries());
        When(joe).AttemptsTo(Click.On(GroceriesForSale.BuyEggsButton));
        var message = Then(joe).ShouldSee(TheText.Of(GroceriesForSale.FeedbackMessage));

        Assert.That(message, Is.EqualTo("Thankyou for buying eggs."));
    }
}
```